# Jasmine - check if variable set from event.target.href

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have some code that looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.link", myFunction);

"myFunction": function (event) {
    var url = event.target.href,
        data = $.get(url, {}, "html");
 ...
```

How can I write a jasmine test to see whether or not the variable "url" is being defined (in particular, defined as an object)?

Answer (score 0):

You can `spy()` on jquery itsef:

```
spyOn($, 'get');
```

and now test:

```
        expect($.get.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toBe(...);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/h03e6mo0/